# How do you print the wrong python file name while serially running multiple python files in a directory?

Tags: python, operating-system, ipython, glob

I am using the below python code to run multiple python files in a directory `D:\PYTHON FILES` using try except method. I need to print the name of the file that has failed to run.Please refer the codes below. Could anyone help me in view of this?

Please Note:

Please run this in DOS prompt and do not use `IPython`. Place all your python files including one corrupt file in the directory `D:\PYTHON FILES`

```
import os, glob
dir='D:\PYTHON_FILES'
os.chdir(dir)

files = glob.glob ('*.py');
for eachfile in files:
    try:
       os.system('python '+eachfile+'\n')
    except:
        print(eachfile + ' missed out')
    finally:
        print('======================')
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `os.system`? It doesn't throw an error, it returns a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned code requires some corrections, for example

```
import os, glob
dir_path = 'D:\PYTHON_FILES'
os.chdir(dir_path)

file_names = glob.glob('*.py')
for file_name in file_names:
    return_value = os.system('python {}'.format(file_name))
    if return_value != 0:
        print('{} missed out'.format(file_name))
print('=' * 24)
```

for more pythonic solution. The non-zero return value signs that there was some problems with the execution of the command of `system` function.